# How can I import html content to pdf template?

Tags: html, templates, pdf, itext, acrofields

I created a pdf template with open office draw. it has textboxes and I can set values with acrofield. But I can't import a html content to template.
I can convert html contents to pdf file; but for template, how can I do it?

My problem is with template; also my html content have to map on page, for example center of page.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure if I understand your question, but it seems like you need some kind of template where you will enter your content.

My thinking goes to OpenXML as the best fit. But since it is rather complex you can save some time by using third party tools.

From my experience, Docentric gives you good value for the money. You can prepare a template in Word and then merge it with data from any source that can fit into .NET object. Your document can be converted to pdf or xps if required.

Templates are generated in MS Word (2007 or newer) using special Docentric Add-in for template generation. All MS Word formatting can be applied here. Placeholders for data are set where the data will appear at runtime.

The process is straight forward so even end users can design reports. Developers then focus on bringing data in from various sources (database, XML). Chech the [product documentation](http://www.docentric.com/documentation/welcome) for ideas how to use it.